# whipped cream icing beforehand vs right before serving

Tags: cake, refrigerator, whipped-cream, icing

I found a recipe of a chocolate poke cake with chocolate ganache in the holes and a whipped cream icing that it's supposed to be only on top, and then with pecans and chocolate flakes and dulce de leche.

The direction say the cake should be served right after making the icing. Is there a particular reason for this?

I'd like to eliminate the dulce de leche and I wonder whether the cake can be done (decorated I mean) a few hours before serving and kept in the fridge.

Can the addition of confectioner's sugar to the whipped cream improve its lifespan of a few hours (and compensate the absence of the supersweet dulce de leche)? thanks

Comment: related, sort of partial duplicate: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/59899/1672

Comment: thanks, it does give the information that cream should be quite firm. But what about Chantilly cream?

Comment: Also doesn't answer about sugar, but does explain how to make it last: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/33405/1672

Comment: If the whipped cream is just going on top, surely you can use any sort of whipped topping you like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whipped cream can be made with unflavored gelatin, so that it will hold its shape for hours; that is how bakeries do it. I did not find it difficult to do the first time I tried it, and was really pleased at how reliably it held up.

http://ourbestbites.com/2015/11/how-to-make-stabilized-whipped-cream/

There are other techniques, but this is an example of how to do it.

Comment: i need to keep it pork-free, and here in Germany gelatine appears to derive from pork. I made a test with Dr. Oetker's "Sahnesteif" that appears to contain only cornstarch. My whipped cream survived perfectly all night in the fridge. Also the taste is OK (I read on amazon's review that Dr. Oetker's "Whip it" sometimes gives the cream a weird taste)